# Deterministic Cipolla's algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms

Cipolla's algorithm for computing square roots in a finite field
([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm))
requires finding $x$ such that $x^2 - a$ is not a square (for computing a square root of $a$).  The usual way to do this is to try random values of $x$ until one verifies this condition.

What about trying $x = 0, 1, 2, ...$ (assuming the field is $GF(p)$ for prime $p$)?  What is known about the smallest integer that verifies the condition (possibly assuming GRH)?

In Tonelli–Shanks' algorithm, we would instead be looking for $y$ that is not a square, and assuming GRH one can prove that the smallest such $y$ in $O(\log(p)^2)$ (even $\leq 2 \log(p)^2$ IIRC, this is due to Bach and can be found in
[Prime Numbers A Computational Perspective](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387252827)
by Crandall and Pomerance). Without GRH, some much weaker bounds are available ($O(p^{1/2})$ is easy IIRC).

My question is whether a similar bound is known for the variant of Cipolla's algorithm that I described above.

Note that I'm not asking whether it is *advisable* to implement the algorithm like this.  Selecting $x$ randomly is certainly easy enough and theoretically well grounded.  However, this question seems natural to me.

I'm pretty sure that no good (meaning, polynomial in $\log(p)$) bound is known without GRH, since it would yield a simple, fully deterministic, polynomial time, algorithm for computing square roots in finite fields, and this would be widely known.

I tried reducing my question to Bach's result, but got stuck.  If $z^2 = a$, then $x^2 - a$ is a square iff $x = z$ or $\frac{x + z}{x - z}$ is a square, and $f: x \mapsto \frac{x + z}{x - z}$ is a bijection on the projective line.  This makes it easy to get a probability for a random $x$ to verify the condition, but $f(x)$ is not necessarily "small" when $x$ is, so I can't relate this to Bach's.